# error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get through Angela Yu's flutter course but the code is outdated. The current issue I am having is with nullable aspect as this wasnt a part of dart when the course was created. Could anyone let me know how I can fix the issue with my tasks List.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'task_tile.dart';
import 'package:todoey/models/task.dart';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TasksListState createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'Buy eggs'),
    Task(name: 'Buy bread'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TaskTile(
          isChecked: tasks[index].isDone,
          taskTitle: tasks[index].name,
          checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
            setState(() {
              tasks[index].toggleDone();
            });
          },
        );
      },
      itemCount: tasks.length,
    );
  }
}
```

```
task.dart file

    class Task {
      final String? name;
      bool isDone;
    
      Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});
    
      void toggleDone() {
        isDone = !isDone;
      }
    }
```

Im not sure what I need to change and why. Thank you

Comment: I added the required keyword and removed the question from the String in the task.dart file and it has seemed to work

Comment: on which file and line you're getting this error?